# Replace multiple regex into one regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

Can I replace following  regex into one regex  in perl

```
message =~ s/&lt;span&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/span&gt;/<span>$1<\/span>/g;
message =~ s/&lt;em&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/em&gt;/<em>$1<\/em>/g;
message =~ s/&lt;ul&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/ul&gt;/<ul>$1<\/ul>/g;
message =~ s/&lt;ol&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/ol&gt;/<ol>$1<\/ol>/g;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
message =~ s#
       &lt;
       (?<tag>span|em|ul|ol)   
       &gt;
       (.*?)
       &lt;
       /
       \k<tag>   
       &gt;
     #
       <$+{tag}>  
       $2    
       </$+{tag}>
     #xg;
```

Comment: This is a very elegant answer, but it isn't strictly speaking equivalent. Compare the result for `encode_entities "<span><em>foo</em></span>". As this answer doesn't recurse, the output would be `<span> &lt;em&gt;foo&lt;/em&gt; </span>`.

Comment: @amon. Yeah, that is an issue. Nested tags is always going to have problem while combining HTML with Regex.

Comment: yes, that's an issue...any solution for Nested tags...I need that for my text conversion...

Comment: @manu. Use appropriate html parser. Regex is not the right tool to parse HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need to capture the content between tags. Why not just replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` around tag names?

```
message =~ s#&lt;(/?(?:span|em|[uo]l))&gt;#<$1>#g;
```